# Bug ao renderizar em produção fontes no NextJS

Tags: javascript, html, react, styled-components, next.js

Fala pessoal!
Eu estou criando um site estático com o NextJS e styled-components.
Tudo ocorre bem no ambiente de desenvolvimento, porém ao colocar em produção as importações de fontes não funcionam.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Impact";
    src: url("/fonts/impact.ttf") format("ttf")
}
```

já desativei os plugins que renderizam o css gerado pelo styled-components no lado do servidor para ver se surtia algum efeito, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: No build gerado, provavelmente deve estar dando um erro 4040 ao tentar acessar o diretório das fontes. Verifique se o path das fontes está correto. Tente inferir de onde está vindo o `url` e ajustar o path na hora de montar o build.

Comment: Opa, o problema era que eu estava importando a fonte errada no styled-components. No ambiente de dev "funcionava", por ser instalada por padrão nos navegadores desktop. Obrigado pela atenção :D

Comment: vlw cara, parabéns. Estamos aqui para ajudar.